# Ajax callback not working. nothing happens after request is sent

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, tomcat, servlets

I am learning jQUery AJAx and used this as a reference: http://www.journaldev.com/4742/jquery-ajax-jsp-servlet-java-example
I am using Tomcat and the following code. When I run tomcat I can reach my site via http://localhost:8080/clientest/ and the input field for the user name shows up. However once I entered a name nothing happened.
I know that the tutorial didn't mention using tomcat. Could that be the problem? I am new to client side programming and servlets so maybe I misunderstood something. I am very grateful if someone could help me.

Servlet:

```
 package org.cc.sbc;
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 import java.io.IOException;

 @WebServlet("/clientest")
 public class SayHelloServlet extends HttpServlet {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String userName = request.getParameter("userName").trim();
    if(userName == null || "".equals(userName)){
        userName = "Guest";
    }

    String greetings = "Hello " + userName;

    response.setContentType("text/plain");
    response.getWriter().write(greetings);

}

}
```

My index.jsp file:

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
     pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
 <html>
 <head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>jQuery, Ajax and Servlet/JSP integration example</title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"
        type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/app-ajax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
  Enter Your Name: <input type="text" id="userName" />
 </form>
 <br>
 <br>

 <strong>Ajax Response</strong>:
 <div id="ajaxGetUserServletResponse"></div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

app-ajax.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#userName').blur(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : 'clientserver',
        data : {
            userName : $('#userName').val()
        },
        success : function(responseText) {
            $('#ajaxGetUserServletResponse').text(responseText);
        }
    });
});
});
```

web.xml:

```
  <web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>SayHelloServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.cc.sbc.SayHelloServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>compilerSourceVM</param-name>
      <param-value>1.8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
      <param-name>compilerTargetVM</param-name>
      <param-value>1.8</param-value>
    </init-param>
  </servlet>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have been looking around on stackoverflow. So I misunderstood my error. Since nothing happened my app-ajax file wasnt even used. It was like there was no additional script at all. Looking at my project structure I had my app-ajax file in a folder js. That was why it was never called. Once I put my app-ajax file in the same directory as my index.jsp file it worked fine. It's not the neatest soluation but it wokrd for me. Should anyone encounter the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

What about your urls:

```
@WebServlet("/clientest")
public class SayHelloServlet extends HttpServlet
```

`/clientest`

```
$.ajax({
        url : 'clientserver',
```

`clientserver`

It should illustrate